# AttributeError: 'ca.report' object has no attribute 'appliquer

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I'm creating a wizard to display revenue by salesman and agency 
when I click on the button "appliquer" I get this error  AttributeError: 'ca.report' object has no attribute 'appliquer'

The code:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
from openerp import models, fields, api
import time
from openerp.exceptions import Warning
from cStringIO import StringIO

class ca_report(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'ca.report'


    vendeur = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='res.users', string=u'Vendeur')
    client_id = fields.Many2many('res.partner',string=u"Client")
    agence_id = fields.Many2many('res.agence',string=u'Agence')

    open = fields.Boolean(string='CA ouvert',help="total amount open")
    draft = fields.Boolean(string='CA brouillon',help="total amount draft")
    paid = fields.Boolean(string='CA validé',help="total amount paid")
    ca = fields.Float(string='chiffre d\'affaire',compute="_get_total_amount")

    date_from =  fields.Date('Start Date')
    date_to =  fields.Date('End Date')


# get invoices by date and status

    def _get_invoice_by_DateAndStatus(self):
        status = []
        if self.open:
            status.append('open')
        if self.draft:
            status.append('draft')
        if self.paid:
            status.append('paid')    

        if status :       
            invoice = self.env['account.invoice'].search([('type', 'in', ['out_invoice']),('state', 'in', status),('date_invoice', '>=', self.date_from),('date_invoice', '<=', self.date_to)])
            return invoice
        else:
            invoice = self.env['account.invoice'].search([('type', 'in', ['out_invoice']),('date_invoice', '>=', self.date_from),('date_invoice', '<=', self.date_to),('state', 'in', ['open','draft','paid'])])
            return invoice    

# get invoices by date, status, agency and/or vendor    

    def _get_invoice_by_Vendor_agence(self):
        all_invoice = self._get_invoice_by_DateAndStatus()

        partner = self.env['res.partner'].search([('user_id', 'in', self.vendeur.ids)])     
        if self.agence_ids and self.vendeur:
            invoice = self.env['account.invoice'].search([('id', 'in', all_invoice.ids),('partner_id', 'in', partner.ids),('agence_id', 'in', self.agence_ids.ids)])
        else:    
            if self.vendeur:    
                invoice = self.env['account.invoice'].search([('id', 'in', all_invoice.ids),('partner_id', 'in', partner.ids)])
            else:    
                if self.agence_ids:
                    invoice = self.env['account.invoice'].search([('id', 'in', all_invoice.ids),('agence_id', 'in', self.agence_ids.ids)])
                else:
                    invoice = all_invoice
        return invoice      
    # Total des factures(ca) "à revoir "

    def _get_total_amount(self):
        invoice_open = self.pool['account.invoice'].search_read(cr,1,[('partner_id','=',o.id),('state','=','open')],['amount_total'],context=context)
        invoice_open_total = sum([x['amount_total'] for x in invoice_open]) or 0

        invoice_draft = self.pool['account.invoice'].search_read(cr,1,[('partner_id','=',o.id),('state','=','draft')],['amount_total'],context=context)
        invoice_draft_total = sum([x['amount_total'] for x in invoice_draft]) or 0

        invoice_paid = self.pool['account.invoice'].search_read(cr,1,[('partner_id','=',o.id),('state','=','paid')],['amount_total'],context=context)
        invoice_paid_total = sum([x['amount_total'] for x in invoice_paid]) or 0

    # afficher le resultat de la demande : 

    @api.multi
    def appliquer(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        context = dict(self.env.context or {})

        def ref(module,xml_id):
            proxy = self.env['ir.model.data']
        return proxy.get_object_reference(module, xml_id)

        model, tree_view_id = ref('account.invoice', 'invoice_tree', 'account.invoice.tree')

        context.update(date_from=self.date_from)
        context.update(date_to=self.date_to)
        context.update(vendeur=self.vendeur)
        context.update(agence_id=self.agence_id)    
        views = [
        (tree_view_id, 'tree'),] 
        domain=[]   
        for x in self.browse(cr,uid,ids):
            if x.vendeur:
                domain.append(('vendeur','=',x.vendeur.id))
            if x.agence_id:
                domain.append(('agence_id','=',x.agence_id.id))
            if x.open:
                domain.append(('ca','=',x.open))
            if x.draft:
                domain.append(('ca','=',x.draft))
            if x.paid:
                domain.append(('ca','=',x.paid))
                #if rec.date_from and rec.date_to:
                #   domain.append (("date_from", "> =", rec.date_from))
                #   domain.append (("date_to", "<=", rec.date_to))  


        return {        
            'name': "Chiffre d'affaire",
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'tree,graph',
            'res_model': 'ca.report',
            'view_id': False,
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'views' : views,
            'domain': domain
            }
```

Comment: Could you please share your xml code?

Comment: Restart Odoo server to be able to call `appliquer` method, and you will get an error when calling `ref`: `TypeError: ref() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <record id="ca_report_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">ca.report.form</field>
        <field name="model">ca.report</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <form string="ca.report">

            <group col="4">
                <field name="date_from" />
                <field name="date_to" />
            </group>
            <group row="3">
            <field name="paid" class="oe_inline" />

            <field name="draft" class="oe_inline" />

            <field name="open" class="oe_inline" />

            </group>
            <group>
                <field name="vendeur"  options="{'no_create':True,'no_create_edit': True}"/>
                <field name="agence_id" />

            </group>
                <button name="appliquer" type="object" string="Appliquer" class="oe_highlight"/>

            <footer>
                <button string="Cancel" special="cancel"/>
            </footer>


            </form>


        </field>  
    </record>                   


    <record id="ca_report_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">ca.report.action</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">ca.report</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="target">new</field>
        <field name="context">{}</field>
    </record>
    <menuitem action="ca_report_action"
        id="ca_report_menu" name="chiffre d'affaire"
        parent="stock.next_id_61" sequence="6" />


</data>
```

Comment: You should edit your question and add this XML code there.